# i want to save multiple images url in realtime database but every time old image url replace by new image url in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies

I want to save multiple images URL in a real-time database but every time an old image URL replace by new image URL in flutter

please help to resolve this problem. I'm new in the flutter

Here is my Code:-

***Flutter***
As you can see in the flutter code I'm  trying to upload multiple images in firebase storage and store image url's in firebase realtime database

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  home: MyHomePage(),
  );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  List<File> imageList = [];
  File? image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  int i = 0;
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

Future _upload() async {
for (var img in imageList) {
  reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('images/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
  await reference.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
    reference.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      i++;
      databaseRef.child("All Data").child("Images").set({"$i": value});
    });
  });
 }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Image upload in firebase flutter"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
          height: height * 0.18,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  width: width * 0.30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.photo_camera,
                        color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                        size: 32,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Add Image",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue.shade900),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  chooseImages();
                },
              ),
              imageList == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Expanded(child: imagesData(imageList))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _upload();
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text("Upload"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

chooseImages() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  imageList.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
});
if (pickedFile == null) retrieveLostData();
 }

Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
final LostData response = await picker.getLostData();
if (response.isEmpty) {
  return;
}
if (response.file != null) {
  setState(() {
    imageList.add(File(response.file!.path));
  });
} else {
  print(response.file);
}
}

Widget imagesData(List<File>? imageList) {
return ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: imageList!.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              child: Image.file(
                imageList[index],
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print("${imageList[index]}");
                setState(() {
                  imageList.remove(imageList[index]);
                });
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            right: 10,
            top: 10,
          )
        ]),
      );
    });
   }
 }
```

code end.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part of the code:

```
 databaseRef.child("All Data").child("Images").set({"$i": value});
```

You are always overriding the same path. Try to use `push` instead of `set`:

```
 databaseRef.child("All Data").child("Images").push({"$i": value});
```

Comment: yes but i want to show images like
images:
 1: imageurl
 2: iamgeurl

Comment: Your question was about `saving` the data and not how to show it. If you don't know how to show the data pls write a new question.